# How to Revoke Automator warning dialog?

Tags: automator

I clicked unwillingly on "Don't show this message" and now it does not appear.

How can I revoke it to be shown as previously?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to "Reset Warnings" in Automator main menu -> 
Reset+Restart Automator:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can probably "uninstall" this particular automator item, then reinstall it, at which point it should behave as it originally did. Assuming this is some an Automator Service or Folder Action you can find the item in ~/Library/Services or ~/Library/Workflows.  To uninstall simply drag to the desktop. To reinstall click on the item and then click the install button.

Comment: It wont work because the behavior is general to all new actions independently of any particular item.